# Science Fiction Book Authored by Female around the early 90's

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a series of books that was authored or co-authored by a female.  I believe it came out in the late 80's or early 90's.

The story had different groups of people in it like borers (people that dug and mined elements or ore), top dwellers, and a special group of people that had abilities where they wrote stories with special ink where the stories or books became other worlds that they manipulated and controlled.  But often these worlds would become unstable.

I just remember getting into this book and never completing or finishing the series.

Anyone remember a series of books like this?  I'm almost certain there was a female author, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: Also,  I believe the title was really short.  Something like "Ayn" "Arne" Ayrn" "Eyrn"

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, you should edit this information into your question.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably the *Myst* novels, based on the bestselling computer game.  The third book was *Myst: The Book of Ti'ana*, written in the voice of a woman (though authored by a man, and most likely one or more uncredited ghost writers).  Ti'ana is the grandmother of Atrus, the adviser character in the original game and protagonist of the first novel.

Ti'ana's primary claim to fame was that she was not D'ni by birth, yet became the first known woman who could "write" -- creating the books that (created/linked to) the worlds, called "ages" that made up the D'ni empire.